# Mef not exporting even when item is imported into catalog

Tags: dependency-injection, mef, containers, composition

Trying to do a import in code so I try this:

```
IServiceBehavior behavior = container.GetExport<IServiceBehavior>().Value;
```

but get this eexception:

```
{"No valid exports were found that match the constraint '((exportDefinition.ContractName == \"System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior\") AndAlso (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey(\"ExportTypeIdentity\") AndAlso \"System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior\".Equals(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item(\"ExportTypeIdentity\"))))', invalid exports may have been rejected."}
```

But when I check the locals for the container MefServiceBehavior, a implementation of IServiceBehavior, is there in the catalog:

```
container   {System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer}    System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer
    -       Catalog {MefContrib.Hosting.Generics.GenericCatalog}    System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartCatalog  {MefContrib.Hosting.Generics.GenericCatalog}
        -       Parts   Count = 6   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartDefinition>
            -       [4] {MyProjectServiceLibrary.Hosting.MefServiceBehavior}    System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartDefinition {System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionComposablePartDefinition}
                -       ExportDefinitions   {System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ExportDefinition[1]}  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ExportDefinition> {System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ExportDefinition[]}
                    -       [System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ExportDefinition[]]   {System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ExportDefinition[1]}  System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ExportDefinition[]
                        -       [0] {MyProjectServiceLibrary.Hosting.MefServiceBehavior (ContractName="System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior")}  System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ExportDefinition {System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionMemberExportDefinition}
                            -       [System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionMemberExportDefinition]    {MyProjectServiceLibrary.Hosting.MefServiceBehavior (ContractName="System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior")}  System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionMemberExportDefinition
                                -       Metadata    Count = 1   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> {Microsoft.Internal.Collections.ReadOnlyDictionary<string,object>}
                                    -       [0] {[ExportTypeIdentity, System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior]}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>
                                                Key "ExportTypeIdentity"    string
                                                Value   "System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior"  object {string}
```

Why doesn't the container find the export. The ExportTypeIdentity is the same as it is mentioned in the exception message. What is going on here?

Comment: I found a really useful tool for debugging MEF composition named mefx.exe that helped me find the problem. It seems that the problem wasn't really with the IServiceBehavior but an Import in it that I hadn't put the type of Export into.

Comment: I'm glad you figured this out.  I'd suggest answering you own question with a link to the mefx tool to help others who find your question by searching.